# Two way data binding issue of \n (new line) while set String into Edittext

Tags: android, html, data-binding, android-databinding, android-textinputlayout

I am facing one issue while set data into Edittext when using **TWO WAY DATA BINDING** 
 **which contain HTML tags like " < br > " or \n.**

when there is \n it next data should be in new line.

it shows me like...

[image]

```
 <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                        android:id="@+id/tiemyComments"
                        android:text="@={myComments}" />
```

Comment: What is the input that generates this in your code? What would be the expected correct output?

Comment: @tomerpacific , when there is \n , next words should be in new line.

Answer (score 1):

there are 3 ways to fixed

1. customize your TextInputEditText class
2. do one method inside you data class and set logic inside that method
   ex user class username contains html text
   so i will do one method like convert htmltoText method and do logic inside that
   method and return string
3. 

```java
public class DataBindingAdapter {
    @BindingAdapter("convertHtmltoText")
    public static void convertHtmltoText(TextInputEditText view, String value) {

        string description = value.replace("\n", "<br/>") ?: ""
        view.setText(HtmlCompl̥at.fromHtml(description, 
 HtmlCompat.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY));

    }
}
```

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
 android:id="@+id/tiemyComments"
 convertHtmltoText="@{myComments} />
```